# Using Align plugin

Tags: alignment

I want to align C variables declariations with [the Align plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Align) using `\adec` as parameter, the problem is that it doesn't do anything.

```
struct mutex {
    pthread_mutex_t listmsg;
    pthread_rwlock_t entity_rw;
};
```

I select the two lines in the struc in visual mode and then enter `:Align \
adec` but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\adec` is not a parameter to `:Align`, it is a key mapping.

Don't type `:Align \adec`

Just hit the keys <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: okay ! and \ is the leader key. Thanks I'm happy now with that plugin in my toolbox :)